# Getting "Communications Link Failure" when connecting to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I am building a Java application that requires a remote DB connection. I have imported the JDBC driver for mysql using Eclipse and as far as I know everything is typed in properly. The server host has enabled my IP to make changes and the username and password have been confirmed.

```
public class Shop {
Connection connection = null;

String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String username = "username";
String password = "password";
String hostURL = "jdbc:mysql://IPAddress:Port/databaseName";


public Shop() {};

public boolean connectDB() {


    try {
        Class.forName(driverName);

        connection =  DriverManager.getConnection(hostURL,username,password);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {  
        System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException : "+e.getMessage()); 
        return false;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getErrorCode());
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
    return true;


}
public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Store");

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Shop s = new Shop();
    System.out.println("Connection : " + s.connectDB());

    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });




}
}
```

Comment: Is the db server remote?  It could be a firewall thing.

Comment: yes it is remote. I will look into the firewall deal

Comment: `telnet ipaddress port` and see if you can connect

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified `IPAddress`, `Port` and the `databaseName`? If so, there's probably a firewall. You can probably setup ssh port forwarding with something like,

```
ssh -L LocalPort:IPAddress:RemotePort username@IPAddress
```

Then you should be able to connect at `localhost:localport`. On Windows, you can use [cygwin](http://cygwin.org/) (as above) or [putty](http://www.putty.org/) (through a simply GUI) exactly the same way. I'm sure there are other options (say a VPN).

Comment: yeah I have verified all of those. I also tried connecting directly with putty earlier to no avail. Can I pass the above command directly through putty on windows?

Comment: In putty you have to use the port forwarding option in the connection setup. Where is the Remote database? Contact the host?

Comment: With cygwin you could run it as above.